# bitmap becomes black after glDeleteTexture

Tags: android, opengl-es, bitmap

I use a SurfaceView on top of a GLSurfaceView (OpenGL ES 2.0 and Android). The GLSurfaceView includes opengl textures which I delete sometimes with glDeleteTexture. The SurfaceView includes a button with a bitmap drawn with canvas.drawBitmap. Sometimes the button gets black and stays like this even if I redraw it. It doesn't happen if I comment out glDeleteTexture. Why? What can I do to still delete the open gl textures and keep the image on the button? Thanks!

Comment: `glDeleteTextures (...)` will implicitly unbind the current texture if one of the textures in the array was actively bound. Without seeing the relevant code it is impossible to say if this is the culprit.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is a lot of code and I don't know what to post. I have the same effect if I just add an Imageview on top of the glsurfaceview. When I call 'GLES20.glDeleteTextures(1, textures, 0);' for an openGlTexture and invalidate the imageView, the image becomes black.